# Implement UIScrollView which holds an image

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I would like to Implement a UIScrollView which should hold an image which is the same width as the screen, but a lot larger in height.

DO I add a UIImageView to the scrollView or how is this done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to go. Don't forget to set the contentSize of the UIScrollView.

Comment: Thanks. What about the delegates. Do they need to be implemented and then add the image? So the scrollview is basically a container?

Comment: You only need to set the delegate and implement the methods for things you are interested in. Yes, it is a container view.